# "Time elapsed" or "elapsed time"

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, adjectives, word-order, past-participles

In a document I have a plot where one of the labels represents the total time taken for the process to complete. Should I label it as "Elapsed Time" or "Time Elapsed"? Which one is correct?

Comment: Both are fine. I've noticed a trend in stopwatches where "Time Elapsed" is preferred. There's no difference, though, until you start creating sentences.

Comment: General Reference. -1 Research not shown. Answers do not belong in comments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"*Elapsed*" is a participle a.k.a. verbal adjective.

As an attributive adjective, it can come either before or after the noun, as long as it is next to it.

And since you're only using it in a label (not in a sentence), both "*elapsed time*" and "*time elapsed*" are correct and possible.

Answer (score 1):

It may be just a matter of style, but I'd prefer "Elapsed Time".  "Elapsed" is an adjective, which normally preceeds the noun.  For a plot label, either is fine.